# getting error getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running php using built-in server as follows:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I am using this code to connect:

```
<?php
$servername="http://127.0.0.1:8000";
$uname="root";
$dbname="student";

if(mysqli_connect($servername,$uname,"",$dbname))
{
    echo "db connected";
}
else
{
    echo "not connected";
}
?>
```

These warnings appear:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in
> /Users/sahilsoni/Desktop/dataconnection.php on line 5

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname
> provided, or not known in /Users/sahilsoni/Desktop/dataconnection.php
> on line  not connected

Comment: 1) mysqli_connect connects to a mySQL server. It doesn't connect to phpMyAdmin (which is just a user interface application and won't return you anything useful). 2) a URL is not a hostname

Comment: Assuming mysql is running on the same machine where phpMyAdmin and your PHP code is located, then try `$servername = "127.0.0.1";` or `$servername = "localhost";`. P.S. Never use `root` as the login for your web application (not even for local testing). It's the super-user admin account, only intended for the database administrator to use. For your application, create a specific mysql user which has only the privileges it actually needs in order to work properly. Otherwise, you're just adding a security risk for no reason.

Comment: This is a HTTP address which is not a valid database hostname. `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Use proper hostname as specified by the database and the right port.